# Pass all rows from a DataGridView on one form to another vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

So i am trying to pass all rows from a DataGridView on a **Button Click** from one form to another. Which is from grd_order in frm_1.vb to grd_invoice in frm_2.vb

This is as far as i can go since i am stil new to vb.net

frm_1.vb

```
Private Sub btn_purchase_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_purchase.Click
      Dim newForm As New frm_2
      newForm.AllRows = grd_order.DataSource
      'what should i put here because the above line is wrong
      newForm.Show()
End Sub
```

frm_2.vb

```
Public Class frm_2
      Public Property AllRows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection
      'I know that DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection is used for the specific row but what about all rows?

      Private Sub frm_2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      'grd_invoice.DataSource = PassText
      'what should i put here
      End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei It is a dynamic DataGridView? Which is initially from `DataTable`. It is actually related to my previous question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648049/pass-data-from-textbox-to-datagridview-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be passing the `DataSource` of your first `DataGridView` to second one.

```
Public Class frm_customer_invoice_a153834
    Public Property Data As Object

    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.grd_invoice.DataSource = Data
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can also define the `Data` property as `DataTable` and pass the data table that you have on your first form, to the second form.

Comment: Okay. LOL i dont know we can pass our datasource. Thank you!

Comment: Just now i checked, i can pass the DataSource, but i need to clear the grd_order too so that it is easy for the user to order. So i use this `grd_order.DataSource = Nothing
                grd_order.Rows.Clear()` and then poof everything is missing on the second form since i clear it. Any chance to make both of it work?

Comment: When you set the datasource of the first grid as datasource of second grid, it's exaclty the same data table. So it shows all rows and columns in the second grid and it uses exactly the same data table. So all changes in your second form will show in your first form when you close the second form.

Comment: okay but is there any chance that i can clear it after i close the second form?

Comment: Yes, simply clear the data of data table using `yourDataTable.Rows.Clear()`. You don't need to clear grid rows.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is what I said in above comment, and you can clear rows of your data table and not the grid. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Pay attention, clearing the `table.Rows.Clear()` will not raise an error but clearing the rows of grid will cause an error `grid.Rows.Clear()`. Also setting the data source to `Nothing` only meas you cut the data-binding relation between grid and data table.

Comment: My bad. So I set `dt` as my datatable. And cleared it. But it clears and passed an empty grid on the second form? Where should i put the clear statement?

Comment: After SecondForm.ShowDialog(), also if you don't use showdialog and you use show, and you want to clear first form grid but have data in your second form grid, pass Clone of the dt to second form.

Comment: DirectCast(Me.grd_order.DataSource, DataTable).Copy() makes a copy of data source of grd_order. This way you are using 2 different table as data sources, so changes on each table, makes no change on other table.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Private Sub btn_purchase_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_purchase.Click
      Dim newForm As New frm_2
      For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In grd_order.Columns
        newform.grd_invoice.Columns.Add(col)
      Next
      For Each row as DataGridViewRow in grd_order.rows

       newForm.grd_invoice.Rows.Add(row)

      next
     newForm.Show()
End Sub
```

hope this helps.